# gsub first word after match

Tags: r, regex

I need to replace only the first word after a match. But all the words are getting replaced after match

The code below replaces all words but i need to remove only `Vehicle Details : Volvo` and `Vehicle Details : scania_z` not all words after the match

Code I tried:

```
ad<-c("Pl. find the Vehicle Details : Volvo needs to be repaired","The vehicle number : 4570d having the Vehicle Details : scania_z should be altered")
s<-gsub("Vehicle Details :*","",ad)
s
```

The expected results is :

```
[1] "Pl. find the needs to be repaired"                         
[2] "The vehicle number : 4570d having the should be altered"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
gsub("Vehicle Details\\s*:\\s*\\w+","",ad)
```

or

```
gsub("Vehicle Details\\s*:\\s*\\S+","",ad)
```

See the  [R demo](https://ideone.com/3L53ZX)

The `\w+` pattern matches 1+ letters, digits or underscores and `\S+` matches 1+ non-whitespace characters. The first one is preferable if you have punctuation at the end of the word that you want to keep, but the latter is best if you just want to remove all non-whitespace chars after `:`.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew , could you also tell me how to keep the 2 words after the match!

Comment: @prog By "keep", do you mean "extract"?  Like [this](https://rextester.com/MOLNM18221)?

Comment: ,by keep i mean remove 2 words instead of 1 word

Comment: @prog `gsub("Vehicle Details\\s*:\\s*\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?","",ad)` or `gsub("Vehicle Details\\s*:\\s*\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)?","",ad)`